# Colourful cryptic

Tags: knowledge, language, geography, cryptic-crosswords

No numbers in this grid. The clues are grouped into 12 squares by the location of the word's first letter. No guesswork is needed – if you have the correct answers, there's only one way to fit the words into the grid.

> [image]

**1. Top left corner**

> a) Filmmaker's static insides (4)
>   b) To move to an African country (4)
>   c) Gene Kelly's film show has overtime (5)
>   d) Dramatist is large number lacking a zero (5)
>   e) Oscar film with no initial reception since (3)
>   f) Dutch DJ's rights to short role-playing game (3)
>   g) Philippine island exhibits yelling at others (4)
>   h) Pacific archipelago with no northerly garment (4)
>   i) Tempest strikes second tree in front of a Swiss belly (7)

**2. Top mid-left**

> a) Imprison gray owls regularly (4)
>   b) Laughing at leading lady's name (4)
>   c) Celestial object programming language (5)
>   d) Celebration is unending collection of stars (4)
>   e) Aquatic organism to not cry in Stampede city (4)
>   f) Retching from top-grade alcohol in practical joke (7)
>   g) Leaders leave Angola, opening new war-torn region (5)

**3. Top mid-right**

> a) Lady from Georgia, Georgia (4)
>   b) Chinese people almost male birds (3)
>   c) Segment of management to complain (3)
>   d) Natural landmark to win back parrot (7)
>   e) Actress Swenson secretly winning awards (4)
>   f) A gram of silver to block someone's mouth (3)
>   g) Italian statistician announced as mythical being (4)
>   h) Maturing banking group has precious metal at the front (5)
>   i) Knock back a rum with water next to great central canyon (5)

**4. Top right corner**

> a) Dylan's haircut (3)
>   b) Union's French water returned (3)
>   c) Junk parking space has bad start (7)
>   d) Eagerly anticipating large orgy every second (4)
>   e) Sausage made with big head and feeling of rage (6)
>   f) A Spanish rum with a thrilling finish is a noble substance (5)

**5. Centre far-left**

> a) Start action! (3)
>   b) Mundane heartless deity (4)
>   c) Taxi of leading resort city (4)
>   d) "Weird Al" in Chinese family (4)
>   e) Historic bird complains endlessly (3)
>   f) Unlimited latte for telecom company (3)
>   g) Bush's hot chocolate without a hot filling (4)
>   h) Barcelona native hides cognac at a landfill (7)
>   i) Mammal to take a small bite out of a flowering plant (3)

**6. Centre mid-left**

> a) Snakes make a haphazard pass (4)
>   b) Panama's alternate motor club (3)
>   c) Well-fed couple mostly amasses mammals (6)
>   d) Unnoted musketeer returns to Dylan's wife (4)
>   e) Whale removed from island's shopping centre (4)
>   f) Crimean battle site initiates home university (4)
>   g) "Grand" tournament is surprisingly small, not large (4)

**7. Centre mid-right**

> a) Carl III displays skinned pagans (5)
>   b) Understand non-confusing end file (4)
>   c) Place to shoot the maximum distance (5)
>   d) Walk by no harbour with travel document (4)
>   e) A bird's top three eight-legged creatures (3)
>   f) Chump with a slow head squeezes out juice (4)
>   g) Famous people refuse tea, resulting in disease (4)
>   h) Agent has an informant with sly heart inside archipelago (7)

**8. Centre far-right**

> a) Mental thorn direction (5)
>   b) Grandma is a precursor to Batman (4)
>   c) Overly combative stag group characters (5)
>   d) Sedative agent crosses off girl's name (3)
>   e) General heads back to criticize someone manipulatively (3)

**9. Bottom left corner**

> a) Snake found on boardwalk (3)
>   b) Deep-voiced sea creature (4)
>   c) Oh my, a clandestine physicist (3)
>   d) Twisted, extreme bunch of Mafiosos (3)
>   e) Montreal player with a bunch to hide (3)
>   f) A common pair with no term for bullets (4)
>   g) Islamic organization is strangely a sham (5)
>   h) Latin person's home with nothing, not even head (4)
>   i) Common first word is commonly third resident organization (4)

**10. Bottom mid-left**

> a) Terror group's goddess (4)
>   b) Woman lies low in Miami (3)
>   c) Dough's spice mix lacks finish (4)
>   d) Contained by Malaysia & Myanmar (4)
>   e) Range conference site head to toe (5)
>   f) Amazon leaders produce Reddit thread (3)
>   g) Mother has key to Mediterranean island (5)

**11. Bottom mid-right**

> a) Deck archiver has overtime (5)
>   b) Gambling, large chancellor (5)
>   c) Short skin ink stored in potatoes (3)
>   d) Hooray, introduction of yet another yoga (3)
>   e) Covered in a veil at a Middle-Eastern resort (5)
>   f) Place down a flower necklace for the audience (3)
>   g) Originally, Englishmen loved youthful Dublin place (3)

**12. Bottom right corner**

> a) Return grain to the path (3)
>   b) Network to fester in the back (3)
>   c) Explorer with a thorn off one side (4)
>   d) A wingless swordsman is a sportsman (3)

Comment: Any reason for the similar letters in different regions of the grid, besides making it harder to fit them together?

Comment: @Deusovi The original idea was to have 4 unique letters in each square, but couldn't quite make it work in this one so I gave up :P Part 2 is under work, though!

Comment: [Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79801) is up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> [image]

**1. Top left corner**

> a) **Filmmaker**'s s(*tati*)c insides (4) - **TATI**
> b) To move to (*to go*) an **African country** (4) - **TOGO**
> c) **Gene Kelly's film** show (*gig*) has overtime (*OT*) (5) - **GIGOT**
> d) **Dramatist** is large number (*googol*) lacking a zero (*-o*) (5) - **GOGOL**
> e) Oscar film (*Argo*) with no initial reception (*-r*) **since** (3) - **AGO**
> f) Dutch DJ's rights (*Tie(sto)*) to **short role-playing game** (*(S)tar (T)rek (O)nline*) (3) - **STO**
> g) **Philippine island** exhibits yellin(*g at o*)thers (4) - **GATO**
> h) Pacific archipelago (*Tonga*) with no northerly (*-n*) **garment** (4) - **TOGA**
> i) Tempest (*storm*) strikes second t(r)ee (*-r*) in front of (*a*) Swiss (*CH*) **belly** (7) - **STOMACH**

**2. Top mid-left**

> a) **Imprison** (g)r(a)y (o)w(l)s regularly (4) - **GAOL**
> b) Laughing (*LOL*) (*a*)t leading **lady's name** (4) - **LOLA**
> c) **Celestial object / programming language** (5) - **ALGOL**
> d) **Celebration** is unending collection of stars (*(gala)xy*) (4) - **GALA**
> e) **Aquatic organism** to not cry in Stampede city (*Calgary - cry*) (4) - **ALGA**
> f) **Retching** from top-(*g*)rade alcohol (*gin*) in practical joke (*gag*) (7) - **GAGGING**
> g) Leaders leave An(*gola*), opening (*n*)ew **war-torn region** (5) - **GOLAN**

**3. Top mid-right**

> a) **Lady** from Georgia, Georgia (*GA-GA*) (4) - **GAGA**
> b) **Chinese people** almost male birds (*(Gan)der*) (3) - **GAN**
> c) Segment of ma(*nag*)ement **to complain** (3) - **NAG**
> d) **Natural landmark** to win back (*gain->niag*) parrot (*ara*) (7) - **NIAGARA**
> e) **Actress Swenson** secretly winn(*ing a*)wards (4) - **INGA**
> f) A (*g*)ram of silver (*Ag*) **to block someone's mouth** (3) - **GAG**
> g) **Italian statistician** announced as mythical being (*genie -> gini*) (4) - **GINI**
> h) **Maturing** banking group (*ING*) has precious metal (*Ag*) at the front (5) - **AGING**
> i) Knock back a rum with water (*grog*) next to gr(*e*)at (*egrog->gorge*) central **canyon** (5) - **GORGE**

**4. Top right corner**

> a) **Dylan's** / **haircut** (3) - **BOB**
> b) **Union's** French water returned (*eau->uae*) (3) - **UAE**
> c) **Junk** parking space (*garage*) has (*b*)ad start (7) - **GARBAGE**
> d) **Eagerly anticipating** l(*a*)r(*g*)e (*o*)r(*g*)y every second (4) - **AGOG**
> e) **Sausage** made with (*b*)ig head and feeling of rage (*anger*) (6) - **BANGER**
> f) (*A*) Spanish rum (*ron*) with a thrillin(*g*) finish is a **noble substance** (5) - **ARGON**

**5. Centre far-left**

> a) **Start (*act*)ion!** (3) - **ACT**
> b) Mundane heartless (*banal - n*) **deity** (4) - **BAAL**
> c) Taxi (*cab*) (*o*)f leading **resort city** (4) - **CABO**
> d) "Weird Al (*la*)" in Chinese (*CN*) **family** (4) - **CLAN**
> e) **Historic bird** complains endlessly (*(moa)n*) (3) - **MOA**
> f) Unlimited l(*att*)e for **telecom company** (3) - **ATT**
> g) **Bush**'s hot chocolate (*cocoa*) without a h(*o*)t filling (*cocoa - o*) (4) - **COCA**
> h) **Barcelona native** hides cogna(*c at a lan*)dfill (7) - **CATALAN**
> i) **Mammal** to take a small bite out of a flowering plant (*?*) (3) - **CAT**

**6. Centre mid-left**

> a) **Snakes** make a haphazard pass (*pass->asps*) (4) - **ASPS**
> b) P(*a*)n(*a*)m(*a*)'s alternate **motor club** (3) - **AAA**
> c) We(*ll*)-fed couple mostly (*amas*)ses **mammals** (6) - **LLAMAS**
> d) Unnoted musketeer (*Aramis - mi*) returns (*aras->sara*) to **Dylan's wife** (4) - **SARA**
> e) Whale removed from island's (*?*) **shopping centre** (4) - **MALL**
> f) **Crimean battle site** initiates home university (*(alma) mater*) (4) - **ALMA**
> g) "**Grand" tournament** is surprisingly small (*small->sllam*), not large (*-L*) (4) - **SLAM**

**7. Centre mid-right**

> a) **Carl** III di(*s*)plays skinned p(*agan*)s (5) - **SAGAN**
> b) Understand non-confusing end (*g(rasp)*) **file** (4) - **RASP**
> c) **Place to shoot / the maximum distance** (5) - **RANGE**
> d) **Walk by** no harbour with travel document (*passport - port*) (4) - **PASS**
> e) **A bird**'s top three eight-legged creatures (*(ara)chnid*) (3) - **ARA**
> f) Chump (*?*) with a (*s*)low head **squeezes out juice** (4) - **SAPS**
> g) Famous people refuse tea (*stars - t*), resulting in **disease** (4) - **SARS**
> h) Agent (*spy*) has an informant (*rat*) with s(*l*)y heart inside **archipelago** (7) - **SPRATLY**

**8. Centre far-right**

> a) Mental thorn (*torn->north*) **direction** (5) - **NORTH**
> b) **Grandma** is a precursor to Batman (*(nana)nanananananaBATMAN!*) (4) - **NANA**
> c) **Overly combative** st(*ag gro*)up characters (5) - **AGGRO**
> d) Sedative agent (*Xanax*) crosses off (*-xx*) **girl's name** (3) - **ANA**
> e) (*Gen*)eral heads back (*gen->neg*) **to criticize someone manipulatively** (3) - **NEG**

**9. Bottom left corner**

> a) **Snake** found on (*boa*)rdwalk (3) - **BOA**
> b) **Deep-voiced / sea creature** (4) - **BASS**
> c) (*Oh m*)y, a clandestine **physicist** (3) - **OHM**
> d) Twisted, extreme (*b*)unch (*o*)f **(*M*)afiosos** (*bom->mob*) (3) - **BOM**
> e) **Montreal player** wit(*h a b*)unch to hide (3) - **HAB**
> f) (*A*) co(*mm*)on pair with no term (*O*) for **bullets** (4) - **AMMO**
> g) **Islamic organization** is strangely a sham (*asham->hamas*) (5) - **HAMAS**
> h) **Latin person**'s (*home*) with nothing (*O*), not (*e*)ven head (*homeo-e*) (4) - **HOMO**
> i) **Common first word** is co(*m*)monly third resident organization (*AMA?*) (4) - **MAMA**

**10. Bottom mid-left**

> a) **Terror group's / goddess** (4) - **ISIS**
> b) **Woman** lies low in (*Mia*)mi (3) - **MIA**
> c) **Doug**h's spice mix lacks finish (*(masa)la*) (4) - **MASA**
> d) **Contained by Malay(*sia*) & (*M*)yanmar** (4) - **SIAM**
> e) **Range** conference site head to toe (*yalta->altay*) (5) - **ALTAY**
> f) (*Ama*)zon leaders produce **Reddit thread** (3) - **AMA**
> g) Mother (*Ma*) has key (*alt*) to **Mediterranean island** (5) - **MALTA**

**11. Bottom mid-right**

> a) **Deck** archiver (*tar*) has overtime (*OT*) (5) - **TAROT**
> b) **Gambling**, large (*L*) chancellor (*Otto*) (5) - **LOTTO**
> c) **Short skin ink** (*(tat)too*) stored in po(*tat*)oes (3) - **TAT**
> d) **Hooray**, introduction of (*y*)et (*a*)nother (*y*)oga (3) - **YAY**
> e) Covered in a v(*eil at*) a **Middle-Eastern resort** (5) - **EILAT**
> f) **Place down** a flower necklace for the audience (*lei->lay*) (3) - **LAY**
> g) Originally, (*E*)nglishmen (*l*)oved (*y*)outhful **Dublin place** (3) - **ELY**

**12. Bottom right corner**

> a) Return grain (*oat->tao*) to the **path** (3) - **TAO**
> b) **Network** to fester in the back (*rot->tor*) (3) - **TOR**
> c) **Explorer** with a (*thor*)n off one side (4) - **THOR**
> d) A wingless swordsman is a sportsman (*?*) (3) - **ORR**