# Headless horseman claims new head

Tags: knowledge, language, geography, cryptic-crosswords

Solve the clues and fit the answers into the grid so that each of the coloured squares contains exactly **four different letters**.

> [image]
>
> 1. Sahara desert capitals of historically African region in Germany (4)
> 2. Fifth Element: Besson's first and last is full of romance gold (5)
> 3. Second detective inside to secretly investigate Scottish river (4)
> 4. Animal with a bull's head, a dog's body and a panda's tail (3)
> 5. College-educated snake brings top backing to African tree (6)
> 6. In Shakespeare's time, has William's wife skipped away? (4)
> 7. Oscar director up front in car radio station's trailers (6)
> 8. Dick does not have a one-in-six chance serving object (4)
> 9. Leaders of kiwi islands banned Mount Cook TV company (4)
> 10. Kazakh reporter misses the last Aboriginal ceremony (4)
> 11. Semitic genitor from a leftist country, not extreme (3)
> 12. Winged beast goes about head hunting, makes money (4)
> 13. Enormous avalanche starting in front, hold fast (5)
> 14. Animal sound is ABBA's half-hearted arrangement (3)
> 15. YouTube singer stays clear of Nazi organization (3)
> 16. Headless horseman claims new head: a northerner (8)
> 17. Metal instrument openers beneath Texas capital (3)
> 18. Saw logs as sensitive about marathon finisher (5)
> 19. Head covering leaves to discuss head covering (3)
> 20. Raspy-voiced bassist takes off cap for award (4)
> 21. Briefly, Barbara's bar bars bar back baloney (4)
> 22. Blake's Adam is not the right side of Harlem (3)
> 23. Selection of divas at a Stockholm attraction (4)
> 24. Christianity contributing to Caribbean Dalma (3)
> 25. Bong from a medical device with no casings (4)
> 26. Intermediates and beginners, among others (2)
> 27. First signs of serious issue to not stand (3)
> 28. Knighted Oscar director left action star (6)
> 29. René Magritte's secret medical procedure (5)
> 30. A Thai sari entangling a Nobel laureate (9)
> 31. Cat's daughter is part of a master race (4)
> 32. Freeman returns to Morgan, for example (4)
> 33. Ooze to snooze without the head loose (4)
> 34. Back stabber cut in, as to talk back (4)
> 35. Food containers covered by bulletins (4)
> 36. Satellite is above the edge of space (3)
> 37. Extremely tiny insectivorous tweeter (3)
> 38. Wheat flour is not fully attainable (4)
> 39. Dumpling baron loses region borders (3)
> 40. Bonapartists lose leading painters (7)
> 41. TV friend's cross bar introduction (4)
> 42. Sailing organization in Casablanca (3)
> 43. Promise to despise without limits (4)
> 44. Spell within the best intentions (5)
> 45. Helps with passes to goal scorer (7)
> 46. Neck hair manner: cut near sides (4)
> 47. Old coins from gold compression (5)
> 48. Operatives eliminate SS dessert (3)
> 49. Pirate phrase from Broken Arrow (3)
> 50. Called out backer at card game (8)
> 51. Islamic veils service contract (3)
> 52. Star Alliance's Swedish front (3)
> 53. City manager plays top record (3)
> 54. Filleted maggot is hot stuff (4)
> 55. Dawn gate dweller's aircraft (5)
> 56. Private airline strike ends (4)
> 57. Raps about woodworking tool (4)
> 58. Pointer hastily cut short (6)
> 59. Corrupted Yemen adversary (5)
> 60. TV network's fundamentals (3)
> 61. Tatum's creative activity (3)
> 62. Beer's phonetic notation (3)
> 63. Paul trimmed incorrectly (3)
> 64. Almost menacing fellows (3)
> 65. California rodent unit (5)
> 66. LOL, decapitated king (3)
> 67. Which is the top hat? (4)
> 68. Falsely mean truly (4)
> 69. Charles's beamer (3)

Hint for #11:

> "Leftist" is meant as a reversal indicator, although as it happens the country in question is indeed leftist.

Comment: Btw, the timing of #7 was completely accidental but I love how it turned out :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Combination of all answers with credits

1. Sahara desert capitals of historically African region in Germany (4)

> SAAR [SAHARA - capitals of 'Historically African' / Saar-region] [elias]

2. Fifth Element: Besson's first and last is full of romance gold (5)

> B(ORO)N ("romance" = romance language) [Michael Siefert]

3. Second detective inside to secretly investigate Scottish river (4)

> SPEY [SPY <- (d)E(tective)] [Rupert]

4. Animal with a bull's head, a dog's body and a panda's tail (3)

> BOA (b+o+a)

5. College-educated snake brings top backing to African tree (6)

> BAOBAB [BA <- (BOA<) + B(acking)] [Rupert]

6. In Shakespeare's time, has William's wife skipped away? (4)

> HATH [Hathaway - away] [Rupert]

7. Oscar director up front in car radio station's trailers (6)

> CABRON [directed by Sam Ainsworth] [why not 'goat' in clue?] [AmI]
>  CUARON [elias]

8. Dick does not have a one-in-six chance serving object (4)

> TRAY [dice holder] [AmI]

9. Leaders of kiwi islands banned Mount Cook TV company (4)

> AORA [Citra satellite pay TV] [elias]

10. Kazakh reporter misses the last Aboriginal ceremony (4)

> [BORA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bora_(Australian)) [BORA(t)] [Rupert]

11. Semitic genitor from a leftist country, not extreme (3)

> ABU [Arabic meaning "father of", CUBA -C reversed] [Joe Lee-Moyet]

12. Winged beast goes about head hunting, makes money (4)

> BAHT [Thai currency] [AmI]

13. Enormous avalanche starting in front, hold fast (5)

> AVAST [AVAlanche + faST] [AmI]

14. Animal sound is ABBA's half-hearted arrangement (3)

> BAA [Somebody]

15. YouTube singer stays clear of Nazi organization (3)

> [TAY](https://www.youtube.com/TayZonday) [STAYS - SS] [Rupert]

16. Headless horseman claims new head: a northerner (8)

> NORSEMAN (horseman-h+n)

17. Metal instrument openers beneath Texas capital (3)

> TIN [Somebody]

18. Saw logs as sensitive about marathon finisher (5)

> SNORE [AmI]

19. Head covering leaves to discuss head covering (3)

> HAT [chat -c] [AmI]

20. Raspy-voiced bassist takes off cap for award (4)

> EMMY - Lemmy minus the 'cap' - Award [CodeBoyCode & RemiHenry]

21. Briefly, Barbara's bar bars bar back baloney (4)

> BABS [AmI]

22. Blake's Adam is not the right side of Harlem (3)

> HAR ([Blake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Har_(Blake))) (NudgeNudge)

23. Selection of divas at a Stockholm attraction (4)

> VASA [selection of "diVAS At" / the Vasa ship] [elias]

25. Bong from a medical device with no casings (4)

> E**PIPE**N -> PIPE [SI.]

26. Intermediates and beginners, among others (2)

> IA [Initial letters of "Intermediates and", Latin "inter alia" = "among others"] [AmI]

27. First signs of serious issue to not stand (3)

> SIT [Somebody]

28. Knighted Oscar director left action star (6)

> chuck NORRIS [Wilma Knight, mother] [AmI]

29. René Magritte's secret medical procedure (5)

> ENEMA [r+ENE MA+gritte] [AmI] (with #16)

30. A Thai sari entangling a Nobel laureate (9)

> AHTISAARI [laureate Martii, anagram AThaisari and sarong ahtisaari] [Joe Lee-Moyet]

31. Cat's daughter is part of a master race (4)

> RYAN [Cat Stevens ..., aryan -a]
>  ARYA (Catelyn Stark's daughter) [elias]

32. Freeman returns to Morgan, for example (4)

> NAME [Freeman reversed: NAMEerf] [elias]

33. Ooze to snooze without the head loose (4)

> SEEP (SLEEP - L) [Michael Siefert]

34. Back stabber cut in, as to talk back (4)

> SASS ? [AmI]

35. Food containers covered by bulletins (4)

> TINS [bulleTINS] [AmI]

36. Satellite is above the edge of space (3)

> ISS: [IS + S(pace)] [Rupert]

37. Extremely tiny insectivorous tweeter (3)

> TIT (tiny...tweeter initialism) grey-tit flycatcher [AmI]

38. Wheat flour is not fully attainable (4)

> ATTA [wheat for flatbread] [AmI]

39. Dumpling baron loses region borders (3)

> BAO [baron -r(egio)n] [AmI]

40. Bonapartists lose leading painters (7)

> ARTISTS [bonapartists - bonap] [elias]

41. TV friend's cross bar introduction (4)

> ROSS [cross -c] [AmI]

42. Sailing organization in Casablanca (3)

> [ASA](https://asa.com/), [Chris B]

43. Promise to despise without limits (4)

> OATH [loathe -l,e] [Joe Lee-Moyet]

44. Spell within the best intentions (5)

> STINT [beST INTentions] [AmI]

45. Helps with passes to goal scorer (7)

> ASSISTS (2x def)

46. Neck hair manner: cut near sides (4)

> MANE [manner -n(ea)r] [AmI]

48. Operatives eliminate SS (3)

> PIE [spies - ss] [elias]

49. Pirate phrase from Broken Arrow (3)

> ARR (ARROW - OW) [Michael Siefert]

50. Called out backer at card game (8)

> BACCARAT (homonym) [Michael Siefert]

51. Islamic veils service contract (3)

> SLA [service level agreement / iSLAmic] [elias]

52. Star Alliance's Swedish front (3)

> **S**tar **A**lliance's **S**wedish = SAS [RémiHenry]

53. City manager plays top record (3)

> PEP - City Manager = Pep Guardiola / (P)lay Record (EP) [SI.]

54. Filleted maggot is hot stuff (4)

> mag+ma -> LAVA [AmI] (gutted :)

55. Dawn gate dweller's aircraft (5)

> PIPER [cub] [AmI]

57. Raps about woodworking tool (4)

> RASP (anagram) [Michael Siefert]

58. Pointer hastily cut short (6)

> CURSOR [CUt ShORt] [cursory -y ?]

59. Corrupted Yemen adversary (5)

> ENEMY (anagram) [elias]

60. TV network's fundamentals (3)

> ABC

61. Tatum's creative activity (3)

> ART ([Art Tatum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_Tatum)) (NudgeNudge)

62. Beer's phonetic notation (3)

> IPA ([Beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India_pale_ale) / [Phonetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)) (NudgeNudge)

64. Almost menacing fellows (3)

> LLW [fellows - foes = llw] [RémiHenry] [Wrong]
>  MEN [MEN(acing)] [Rupert] [Correct]

65. California rodent unit (5)

> CARAT (CA + RAT, carat is a unit of mass) (NudgeNudge)

66. LOL, decapitated king (3)

> HAH [shah -s] [Joe Lee-Moyet]

67. Which is the top hat? (4)

> THAT [The (top) + HAT = which] [JonMark Perry]

68. Falsely mean truly (4)

> AMEN (anagram of 'mean') [elias]

69. Charles's beamer (3)

> RAY [Ray Charles / ray beam] [elias]

Filling these into the crossword:

> [image: crossword]

Comment: @jafe are these correct so far? thanks!

Comment: 4, 16 & 45 are correct.

Comment: 20. Raspy-voiced bassist takes off cap for award (4) : answer(Emmy) - Lemmy minus the 'cap' (L)Emmy - Award - Emmy

Comment: 1. Sahara desert capitals of historically African region in Germany (4): ARID? - Capitals of "African Region In" + D = Germany (not sure about the 'historically'...)

Comment: @JoeLee-Moyet, ARID does not seem to fit anywhere in the crossword, I'm afraid

Comment: @elias fair enough, thanks.
43: Promise to despise without limits (4) - OATH [LOATHE - LE]

Comment: 9. Leaders of kiwi islands banned Mount Cook TV company (4) - this should be something AOR?, AORA maybe? Leaders of kiwi islands are MAORI, I think, but how to proceed?

Comment: 30. A Thai sari entangling a Nobel laureate (9) -> [Martti] AHTISAARI (anagram of "A Thai sari")

Comment: 66. LOL, decapitated king (3): HAH ("Shah" decapitated)

Comment: I've added a few more to the spreadsheet linked to my answer. Some of them might be incorrect, and some out of my understanding - but fit in the crossword nicely.

Comment: Not sure about clue 11 -- Hindi is not semitic, and why is 'City manager' in clue 53?

Comment: 31 is wrong, but funnily enough that answer is correct for another clue.

Comment: Also #26 is wrong. Everything else is correct so far, although some of the reasonings need work and there's a typo in #30.

Comment: Yeah, #31 should be ARYA (Catelyn Stark's daughter)

Comment: #24 - Christianity contributing to Caribbean Dalma (3) - TIA chris-TIA-nity - Tia Dalma actress in the Pirates of the Caribbean?

Comment: Looks like #11 should be ABA in the end. No idea about how we should arrive to that though.

Comment: @elias #11 is not ABA, THA or THI :)

Comment: which one can be the definition of ABU?

Comment: Looks like #11 is ABU (CUBA -C reversed) - https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2006/07/abu-ibn-and-bin-oh-my.html

Comment: @elias with  #67 = THAT (as already filled in above) I think you've now enough to complete the grid?

Comment: @JoeLee-Moyet IIRC, we were hinted earlier that 67 is neither THAT or WHAT. I cannot find that now though, so I've added it to the spreadsheet, and will include a screenshot in a minute or two.

Comment: Everything's correct. Nice work, everyone!

Comment: an upvote for all of you who contributed to this answer. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 9):

I'm new around here but I love cryptics so I wanted to see if any of my answers were correct.

14. Animal sound is ABBA's half-hearted arrangement (3)

> Baa

17. Metal instrument openers beneath Texas capital (3)

> Tin

20. Raspy-voiced bassist takes off cap for award (4)

> Ward (edit: incorrect, per OP)

27. First signs of serious issue to not stand (3)

> SIT

36. Satellite is above the edge of space (3)

> EOS

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! 14 & 17 are correct. For 20 you found an answer which works but isn't the one I intended...

Comment: Thanks! I added A couple more before I go back to working

Answer (score 5):

A few more:

2. Fifth Element: Besson's first and last is full of romance gold (5)

> B(ORO)N  ("romance" = romance language)

33. Ooze to snooze without the head loose (4)

> SEEP (SLEEP - L)

49. Pirate phrase from Broken Arrow (3)

> ARR (ARROW - OW)

50. Called out backer at card game (8)

> BACCARAT (homonym)

57. Raps about woodworking tool (4)

> RASP (anagram)

Answer (score 4):

Partial as well :

2. Fifth Element: Besson's first and last is full of romance gold (5) [Wrong]

> **B**esso**N** + **R**omance + **AU** (gold) = BRAUN

7. Oscar director up front in car radio station's trailers (6)

> O D U -> RON = RODUON

8. Dick does not have a one-in-six chance serving object (4)

> DICE

13. Enormous avalanche starting in front, hold fast (5)

> **FRO**nt + fa**ST** = FROST

20. Raspy-voiced bassist takes off cap for award (4)

> LEMMY = EMMY

52. Star Alliance's Swedish front (3) [Correct]

> **S**tar **A**lliance's **S**wedish = SAS

62. Beer's phonetic notation (3) [Wrong]

> BIR

63. Paul trimmed incorrectly (3) [Wrong]

> PAU / AUL

64. Almost menacing fellows (3) [Wrong]

> fe**ll**o**w**s - foes = LLW

Comment: 52 is correct :)

Answer (score 4):

42. Sailing organization in Casablanca (3)

> ASA

58. Pointer hastily cut short (6)

> cursory  CURSOR

60. TV network's fundamentals (3)

> ABC

Answer (score 4):

25. Bong from a medical device with no casings (4)

> E**PIPE**N -> PIPE

53. City manager plays top record (3)

> PEP - City Manager = Pep Guardiola / (P)lay Record (EP)

48. Operatives eliminate SS dessert (3)

> PIE (Dessert) / Operatives eliminate SS => SPIES -SS

Answer (score 3):

20. Raspy-voiced bassist takes off cap for award (4) :

    > (Emmy) - Lemmy minus the 'cap' (L)Emmy - Award - Emmy

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>  +++B +BAA NORS EMAN SVA+
>  +BAO BABB ORON NAME LAVA
>  +AOR ACAB RONO ENEM ASAS
>  BOAA BCCU RSOR MENM SASS
>  AHTI SAAR ISPE YTAY TITI
>  HAHH ARRA SPIP AART ISTS
>  TTIA SAAR PIPE RRYA NSIT
>  THAT ATTA SEEP TRAY TINS
> ```
>
> decided HHAT is better than AHAT (but this is still wrong) 　　
>  decided IA is better than HA (and TIA is an actual person)　　
>  see that THAT was only marked wrong because it was listed with WHAT